# Secure DBT packages

Tags: github, package, dbt

I have a git repo of dbt project. I want to use the macros from this project in a new dbt project. So, I call on that repo in packages.yml file of working dbt project.

Is there any way to secure the package with keypair/credentails so that not everyone allowed to import that package from github?

Comment: It sure is. How are you deploying dbt? Are you using dbt Cloud or something else? See https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/packages#private-packages

Comment: I am using dbt core. Thank you @tconbeer